# Dart: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Flutter application and I am stuck at while implementing Firebase.

```
    enter  return Container(
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: quizStream.snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return snapshot.data != null
                  ? Container()
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return QuizTile(
                          ImgUrl: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()["imgdesc"] ,
                        );
                      });
            }));
  }
```

`ImgUrl: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()["imgdesc"]`

This is the line where I am getting an error and it tells me:

> the operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'. Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: Does this help: `(snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map)["imgdesc"]`

Comment: can you add an example of  the data that this method receive

Comment: Paste the complete code with the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it as `Map<String,dynamic>`

```
ImgUrl: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map<String,dynamic>["imgdesc"],
```

Or use this:

```
ImgUrl: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('imgdesc'),
```

Comment: Yeah using the get function worked for me. Actually the data property is now a function. Thanks btw

Comment: Great, please consider marking it as the correct answer to your question. Thanks