# get values from an array in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

i want to get values from an array field.

but i got an error

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (Documentation)  Try defining the operator '[]'.`from this code`var followedSitesList = value.data()!["followedSites"];

```
getNotificationData(BuildContext context) {
  CollectionReference notReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("notifications");
  CollectionReference siteReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("sites");
  CollectionReference userReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  messaging.getToken().then((value) {

    userReference.snapshots().forEach((users) {
      print(users.docs.map((user) {
        
        if(user["userToken"] == value ){
        
          siteReference.snapshots().forEach((sites) {
            sites.docs.map((site) {
              
              userReference.doc(user.id).get().then((value) {

                var followedSitesList = value.data()!["followedSites"];
              });
            });
          });
        }}));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: first u gotta convert it to a list ( value.data()!["followedSites"] ) . then defice var followedSitesList = converted "followedSites"

Comment: @JBJason may i want can you write it as code?

Comment: u can use this site to generate the code for u.  https://quicktype.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
value.data()!["followedSites"]
```

As the error message says, the `value.data()!` here is an `Object` and you can call `["followedSites"]` on an object.

You know that `value.data()!` is a `Map`, so you should tell the compiler that with:

```
var values = value.data()! as Map;
var followedSitesList = values["followedSites"]
```

Also see:

- [The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'. Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245865/the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-class-object-dart)
- [Dart: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'. Try defining the operator '[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72157400/dart-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-object-function-try-def)
- [FLUTTER The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547592/flutter-the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-type-object)